# Java calling Python (class, interface, or enum expected)

Tags: java, python, compilation, compiler-errors

I have created a java program that calls a python script

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("cmd /c python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10");
```

When I compile I get error:

```
call_py.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
^
call_py.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Process p = r.exec("cmd /c python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10");
^
2 errors
```

Both java program and python script are in the same directory, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, you can just execute code, but in Java, it's not that easy.

You need to put your code inside a method inside a class.

Try creating a file named "PythonCallTest.java" with the following contents:

```
public class PythonCallTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec("cmd /c python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10");
    }
}
```